# ASP.NET Core - Can't serialize JSON for sending to another API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serialization, json.net, automapper

Have an ASP.NET Core Web API with some services.

I have a database entity `Products`:

```cs
public class Products
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public bool InStock { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

and a model class working with `Products`:

```cs
public class ProductModel
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
}

public class ProductListModel
{
    [JsonPropertyName("data")]
    public List<ProductModel> ProductList { get; set; }
}
```

I need to take my products from my database and send them to an external API. But that external API needs JSON format like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "ProductId": 1,
      "ProductCode": "000001AD"
    },
    {
      "ProductId": 2,
      "ProductCode": "000001AB"
    },
    {
      "ProductId": 3,
      "ProductCode": "000002AA"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'll take data from the database:

```cs
var products = _context.Products.Where(x => x.InStock).ToList();
```

Then I use AutoMapper, but `test.data` always returns null:

```cs
var test = new ProductListModel();
_mapper.Map(products , test.ProductList);
```

But, if I serialized like this (without AutoMapper):

```cs
var products = _context.Products.Where(x => x.InStock).ToList();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(products );
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductListModel>(json);
```

On the last line with the `model` variable, I get this error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'MyProject.Test.Models.ProductListModel' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
> Path '', line 1, position 1.'

How can I take records from the database, put them in "data" and not get an error?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `_mapper.Map(products, test.data);` this line doesn't look correct, did you mean `_mapper.Map(products, test.ProductList);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution: AutoMapper**

Your Mapping Configuration / Profile should be as below:

```cs
MapperConfiguration _config = new MapperConfiguration(config => 
{
    config.CreateMap<Products, ProductModel>(); 
            
    config.CreateMap<List<Products>, ProductListModel>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductList, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));   
});
```

> Mapping function

```cs
var test = new ProductListModel();
_mapper.Map(products, test);
```

Or

```cs
var test = new ProductListModel();
test.ProductProductList = _mapper.Map<List<ProductModel>>(products);
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TVplTC)

---

**Solution: For *Newtonsoft.Json* Deserialize**

`products` is `List<Products>` type. When you try to deserialize the JSON, you should deserialize it as the `List<ProductListModel>` type.

```cs
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProductListModel>>(json);
```

---

**Side note**

`JsonPropertyName` attribute is used for *System.Text.Json*

```cs
[JsonPropertyName("data")]
```

`JsonProperty` attribute is used for *Newtonsoft.Json*

```cs
[JsonProperty("data")]
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need any mapper, just fix your code. You are trying to deserialize List as ProductListModel, but they are very different. try this

```
var products = _context.Products
                        .Where(x => x.InStock)
                        .Select(x=> new ProductModel {
                               ProductId=x.ProductId,
                               ProductCode=x.ProductCode
                               })
                        .ToList();

ProductListModel productListModel= new ProductListModel { ProductList = products };

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(productListModel);

ProductListModel model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductListModel>(json);
```